# Get certain text replace it and wrap it in span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html`<p class="get">This is some content.</p>` what I would like to do is to make it like this:`<p class="get">This is <span>some</span> content.</p>`. 
To accomplish this I know I should: 1. get my certain text (done that...) 

                                                       2. Wrap my text in span (done that also...)

                                                       3. replace my text with text that contains my span **(haven't done it)**

My problem is **step 3** I just can't figure it out. So how can I replace my "old" text with new one?
Thank you guys!!!

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/V7Wnk/)

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//get the whole text
var ptext = $(".get").text().split(" "); 
var myText = ptext[2]; 
//alert(ptext[2])
//alert(myText);
if($('.get').text().contains(myText)){
//$('<span>'+myText+'</span>').appendTo($('.get'));
}
else{
alert('no text');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.get').html(function (i, v) {
    return v.replace('some', '<span>some</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var word = "some",
    regex = new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b", "g");

$(".get").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(regex, "<span>$&</span>");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/V7Wnk/1/

Comment: Why the need for a regex (unless the actual text way is more complex than the example)? If you *do* need a regex, why not a literal one?

Comment: @JosephSilber Regex gives a possibility to make global replace. Moreover, it is more flexible for single word detection.

Comment: ...which isn't in the example. But even then, why not a literal regex?

Comment: @JosephSilber Of course in order to show how to use it with different words.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.get').html($(".get").html().replace("some","<span> some </span>"));
```

Comment: Better to use function arg of the `.html` function for this specific case.